# working xml disappeared in emulator or phone

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've been working on my application, in android, for quite some time now when suddenly my layout started messing up with me. I"ve a client server based game which was working pretty fine until i dont know what happened that the xml disappears on the emulator and even when testing on the phone. However, it reappears after a number of tries but takes couple of days at times. Also, note that the functionality of the screen with missing buttons still works but that area of the layout remains invisible. The game fetches data from the server which is currently hosted on my PC from where i'm testing it.

Please help to understand what could be the reason. I'm clueless...

Answer (score 0):

This type of behavior can be happened if the application is not properly Build. Try **Clean + Build** your application every time you want to test it.

Comment: Did that multiple times, but didn't help. Recent thing that I've seen is if you compile the same code on someone else's PC it'll start working and back on my PC as well. But after few executions, same behaviour :(